# Scaffold content is not respect my topBar compose kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i'm trying to do this code

```
class FormActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FormContent()
        }
        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
            this,
            object: OnBackPressedCallback(true
        ) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                finish()
            }
        })
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    @Composable
    private fun FormContent() {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TutorialTopBar(
                    text = "FormScreen",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    onNavigationClick = {
                        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                    },
                    onNavigationIcon = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack
                ).TopBar()
            },
            content = {
                FormFields()
            }
        )
    }

    @Composable
    private fun FormFields() {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inversePrimary)
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = "asdasdasd",
                onValueChange = {},
                label = {
                    Text(text = "Label")
                }
            )
        }
    }

    @Preview(showBackground = true)
    @Composable
    fun ShowPreview() {
        FormContent()
    }
}
```

I wanna see in the preview all my screen :
TopBar
Content

the content have OutlinedTextField that is not be shown because its behind the TopBar.
Why the Scaffold is not respect the topbar area and content area ?

[image: Image with Content behind the TopBar]
[image: How i wanna see in preview]

What im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the `Scaffold` composable should have a `PaddingValues` in the `Content` lambda that should be used in the top composable that is located inside content so you should do something like this:

```
 Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TutorialTopBar(
                    text = "FormScreen",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    onNavigationClick = {
                        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                    },
                    onNavigationIcon = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack
                ).TopBar()
            },
            content = {paddingValues->
              Box(
                 modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues),
                 contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
              ) {
                FormFields()
              }
            }
        )
```

as you can see i added a container `Box` that has a modifier `padding` and you pass the `paddingValues` given from `Scaffold` to it.